# Auto layout: constraint that involves multiple items

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, user-interface, autolayout

For example, I want a certain text field to be placed below the navigation bar with a distance equal to a quarter of the total height of the superview. This involves three items: the text field, the top layout guide, and the superview. How can one create such constraint, either in Interface Builder or by programming?

Comment: One way is to create an oulet reference of the constraint and change its constant value programmatically (to be a quarter height of the superview) in viewWillLayoutSubviews

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez: In this specific case, that works because the superview never changes. But what about more general case? Like when the constant is the attribute of another text field which is also subject to adjustments by auto layout system?

Comment: @BenjaminJimenez: Scratch that. When the user rotate the device, the superview will change.

Comment: Yes but when the user rotates viewWillLayoutSubviews si called again, So now it will be 1/4 of the rotated view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do with one constraint. Instead you need to create an extra `UIView` above the text field. Then you can set the following contraints:

1. 4 * extraView.height = containerView.height
2. extraView.top = topLayoutGuide
3. extraView.bottom = textField.top

Comment: `UILayoutGuide` is better than a dummy `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you need something like this, and don't want to use the Benjamin's technique, use the multiplier property of an equal width or height constraint to the superview.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do it is using constraintsWithVisualFormat. Like so:

```
double quarterSuperViewHeight = superView.frame.size.height / 4;
NSDictionary* metrics = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(quarterSuperViewHeight);
NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(textField, navigationBar);
[superView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"[navigationBar]-quarterSuperViewHeight-[textField]" options:0 metrics:metrics: views:views];
```

This should set the space between the navigation bar and the text field to a quarter of the superview's height. Now I can't quite remember if you'll have to redo this layout everytime the device rotates, but I don't think you should.